# Identify similar features from a set of features for a given feature in an unsupervised learning way

Tags: feature-selection, unsupervised-learning

Suppose I have a set of 1000 features. Now for a given feature, how to find the similar features from this 1000 features in an unsupervised learning way? In other words, no target/label dataset is provided.

Comment: What kind of feature(s)? Numeric, factor, string...?

Comment: You can assume all of them are numerical features.

Comment: you can try various correlation tests between features, eg form the covariance matrix